# Get AudioSource from other Gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I use the AudioSource component of a Gameobject to another Gameobject?.

GameObject1.AudioSource

In gameobject2 I will use the GameObject1.AudioSource..

I'm using Unity3d and c# lang.

Please Help..

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are looking for this:

```
AudioSource source1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameObject1").GetComponent<AudioSource>();

GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = source1.clip;
```

This finds a gameObject with tag (this step is optional if you already have GameObject1) and gets the clip from its `AudioSource` component and copy to GameObject2's AudioSource. In the same way you can read other  properties from audio source1.

Answer (score 0):

Well a general way to get a component would be from the editor, you could write something like this

```
public Audiosource otherGameObjectAudioS;
```

Then you could assign it manually on the editor dragging the game object i the field of the variable created and Unity will automatically get the audiosource component so you could use it.

```
otherGameObjectAudioS.PlayOneShot(audioClip);
```

although if assigning it from the editor is not possible, you should specify when do you want to access it, because there are multiple ways to do it, like on collisions, finding the specific object, etc.

Cheers